# Get Selected dropdown options use Axios on laravel 8

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, axios

now i'm making same project using laravel 8. i integrate AXIOS on it. right now, i not able to get selected dropdown option if function validation detect error input when do submit.

basically, i made code for display state when user select the country. but still confuse how to get selected state when have error on validation.

this is my code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {  

        if($('#selectCountry').val() != ""){

            var chooseCountry = $('#selectCountry').val(); 

            axios.post('/getState', {country_id: chooseCountry  }).then(function(res) {  
                $('#selectstate').html('<option value="">Select State</option>');
                $.each(res.data, function (key, value) { 
                    $('#selectstate').append('<option value="' + value.id + '" {{ old("state_id") == '+value.id+' ? "selected" : "" }} >  ' + value.state_name + '</option>');
                });  
            }); 
        }  
    });
</script>
```

how to improve my code to able get selected state.
please help

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: no error. just can't display selected options. it always return to "select State"

Comment: where is the event listener for the select input?

Comment: axios will not execute if the value is empty, is it not empty?